# django-rest-framework – how to serialize nested objects?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an api endpoint that pulls all the `FeaturedProvider` and `Testimonial` objects from the database, serialize it and return it as a new serialized object `HomepageContentSerializer`

I've tried multiple ways but I'm getting empty `{}` when I try to hit the endpoint. I'm not sure where to initialize or pass the `FeaturedProvider` and `Testimonial` objects to the `HomepageContentSerializer` to be serialized

`serializers.py`

```
class FeaturedProviderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FeaturedProvider
        fields = '__all__'


class TestimonialSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Testimonial
        fields = '__all__'


class HomepageContentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    providers = FeaturedProviderSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    testimonials = TestimonialSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

`views.py`

```
class HomepageContent(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
    def get(self, request):
        content = HomepageContentSerializer().data
        return Response(content)
```

My goal is to get this representation back

```
{
    "providers": [
        { ... },
        { ... },
        { ... },
    ],
    "testimonials": [
        { ... },
        { ... },
        { ... },
    ],
}
```

Comment: You're not passing any data to the serilaizer so of course you get an empty JSON response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing any data to the serializer so that is why you are getting an empty JSON response. The serializer does not fetch data from DB on its own. The data gets passed to it. You will also need a data structure that matches the `HomepageContentSerializer`.

You can use namedtuples.

```
from collections import namedtuple

HomePageContent = namedtuple('HomePageContent', ['providers', 'testimonials'])

class HomepageContent(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
    def get(self, request):
        providers = Provider.objects.all()
        testimonials = Testimonial.objects.all()
        home_page_data = HomePageContent(providers=providers, testimonials=testimonials)
        content = HomepageContentSerializer(home_page_data).data
        return Response(content)
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked. I wasn't sure how to pass the querysets to `HomepageContentSerializer`

Comment: Glad it helped.